# Redirecting to URL with Query String Properly in Express

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I have the following code:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  req.query.searchQuery = 'test2'
  res.redirect('/search');
});

app.get('/search/', function (req, res) {
  var searchQuery = req.query.searchQuery;
  res.send(searchQuery);
});
```

I am trying to understand how I can pass and receive a query string as later on I want to implement a search functionality. When I navigate to '/' it will redirect to '/search' but not respond with the search query. However, if I replace the top route with this:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  req.query.searchQuery = 'test2'
  res.redirect('/search?searchQuery=' + req.query.searchQuery);
});
```

It will redirect to '/search?searchQuery=test2' and the '/search' get handler will print out the query. However, I am not sure if this is the proper way of handling query strings in Express as I could not find any documentation on this kind of example.

Answer (score 0):

I always do it like your last code and I am almost sure it is the correct way to do it.
Why would you want to do it otherwise?

```
res.redirect('/route?searchQuery=' + searchQuery);
```